# PreferredSize and GetX usage

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

My AppBar has git bottom properties and executing `BottomOfAppBar` class but flutter ignoring `preferredSize` in this class.

My goal is make AppBar's height to set 0px if TabBar is disabled. (tabbarenable2 value makes own main goal but I could not find a way to set the AppBar's height dynamically)

here is the code:

```
class BottomOfAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  final TabBarController controller;

  BottomOfAppBar({Key? key, required this.tabs, required this.controller})
      : super(key: key);
  final List<Widget> tabs;
  final tabbarenable2 = Get.find<RxBool>(tag: 'tabbarenable');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: tabbarenable2.value
            ? const Size.fromHeight(28.0)
            : const Size.fromHeight(0.0),
        child: ColoredBox(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              tabbarenable2.value
                  ? TabBar(
                      labelColor: Colors.purple[100],
                      indicatorColor: Colors.purple,
                      isScrollable: true,
                      labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                      tabs: tabs)
                  : const Text('noTabBar')
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize =>
      tabbarenable2.value ? Size.fromHeight(28.0) : Size.fromHeight(0.0);
}
```

any help?

first launch everything seems ok:

[image]

navigate to video (`tabbarenable` = false)

[image]

it is correcting own only to first refreshing the page (correct tabBar height)

[image]

Comment: Could you support your question with images to show your output?

Comment: added the images. GetX does not apply the preferredSize values

Comment: ""var tabbarenable2 = Get.find<RxBool>(tag: 'tabbarenable');"" inside the build method then run the app.... you made the tabbarenable2 final which is not allowing it to rebuild the value as the state changes dynamically. you need to place it inside the build method

Comment: if I move final tabbarenable inside to build method and change final to var I getting error for this line: `Size get preferredSize =>
      tabbarenable2.value ? Size.fromHeight(28.0) : Size.fromHeight(0.0);`tabbarenable2 undefined name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay just try the following snippet and in case it does not work, please let me see the usage

- what try I do here is makes a check before displaying the widget and maybe the right place will be in "bottomAppBar: [check here]"

- Note do not check the boolean value in the build method as it is a bad way to rebuild the widget over and over.

  ```
  class BottomOfAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  final TabBarController controller;

  BottomOfAppBar({Key? key, required this.tabs, required this.controller})
  : super(key: key);
  final List<Widget> tabs;
  final tabbarenable2 = Get.find<RxBool>(tag: 'tabbarenable');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => !tabbarenable2.value
            ? SizedBox() : PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(28.0),
    child: ColoredBox(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.purple[100],
                  indicatorColor: Colors.purple,
                  isScrollable: true,
                  labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                  tabs: tabs)
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize =>
  tabbarenable2.value ? Size.fromHeight(28.0) : Size.fromHeight(0.0);
  }
  ```

Comment: there is no change with the original. It works only if I visit video again.
`bottom: BottomOfAppBar(tabs: tabs, controller: controller)),`this class triggering from here.

Comment: try to update the following:


`bottom: BottomOfAppBar(tabs: tabs, controller: controller)),`

to be 


`bottom: Obx(() => Get.find<RxBool>(tag: 'tabbarenable') ? SizedBox() : BottomOfAppBar(tabs: tabs, controller: controller))),`


and be sure the value of -Get.find<RxBool>(tag: 'tabbarenable')- is updating as well

Comment: with your bottom code I am getting this error: `The argument type 'Obx' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'.`

Comment: Oops, plz wrap your **scaffold** with Obx() instead of wrapping the **bottom:** content

Comment: I can wrap Scaffold but if try to get the value of tabbarenable I am getting this error: `Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'. Try changing the condition.`

Comment: you mean after using `Get.find<RxBool>(tag: 'tabbarenable')`

Comment: yes, after checking the current status of tabbarenable

Comment: send me your current code pls.

Comment: solved with the help of @muhamed-jalal. Thanks

Comment: Good to know, happy coding:)

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the BottomOfAppBar class and I moved the code to Scaffold Widget. Wrapped with 0bx() and changed the check mechanism with `controller.tabbarenable.value` many thanks for @muhamed-jalal